# where does Jackrabbit store its tree information

Tags: jackrabbit

I am a newbie to Jackrabbit. I wonder where Jackrabbit store its tree information. I want to access to the tree information in real time, even i restart my program. It should behave like the tree information is stored in the file system permanently. But now if I stopped my program, all the Jackrabbit tree information will be lost. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackrabbit can use different PersistenceManagers to store the content, if you're using a TransientRepository, for example, the content isn't persisted as that's meant for testing only.

See http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It clears the problem a lot. I want to store the content information in the file system. How can I configure the jackrabbit, like the repository.xml? Thanks again.

Comment: Hello Bertrand, I still cannot make it work in my codes. Is there a tutorial or sample code for this configuration? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should probably start with the Jackrabbit standalone jar file, which does not require an external database, see http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html